# Restore Database from Codeigniter Backup

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was trying to make an automated database backup using built-in CodeIgniter `$this->dbutil->backup()`.

The script is:

```
    $this->load->dbutil();

    $backup = $this->dbutil->backup(array(
        'tables'        => array(),   // Array of tables to backup.
        'ignore'        => array('regencies', 'villages', 'provinces'),                     // List of tables to omit from the backup
        'add_drop'      => TRUE,                        // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
        'add_insert'    => TRUE,                        // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
        'newline'       => "\n"                         // Newline character used in backup file
    ));

    $this->load->helper('file');

    $latest = md5(uniqid());

    write_file(APPPATH . 'backup/'. $latest .'.gz', $backup);
```

The scripts run just fine. But the problem comes when i wan't to restore. It comes like this:

[image: sql result of the codeigniter backup]

As a result of that i cannot restore it from CLI (`mysql -u root -p dbname < db.sql`) and from Navicat/Sequel Pro.

[image: restore database from cli]

The question is, how to restore that it to database again? (Notice that there's no quot after VALUES)

Comment: make your life easier and use this: https://github.com/gocom/danpu even works with triggers... simply require it and load it with `new Export` .etc.

Comment: Well, i already changed to mysqldump-php, Thankyou anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple SQL syntax issue.  String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`,`bell`) VALUES ( Hey diddle diddle , cat and fiddle )
```

won't work. We need

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`bar`,`bell`) VALUES ('Hey diddle diddle','cat and fiddle')
                                         ^-----------------^ ^--------------^
```

Take a closer look at the actual SQL statement you are trying to execute.

Your "unloader" is going to need to be smarter, enclosing string and date values in single quotes when they get put into a SQL statement.  (For convenience, numeric literals can be enclosed in single quotes as well, so you don't need to discriminate, just enclose all values in the `VALUES` list in single quotes.

Also be aware of what will happen when a value includes a single quote. For example:

```
 ... VALUES ( 'O'Leary' , ... 
              ^_^
```

That's also going to be an error.  Single quotes within a value will need to be escaped. One way to do that in MySQL is to precede a single quote with another single quote, like this:

```
 ... VALUES ( 'O''Leary' , ... 
              ^--------^
```

This would be valid, and would evaluate to a string containing a single single quote `O'Leary`

Also, MySQL will interpret a backslash character in a string literal as an escape character. For example:

```
 ... VALUES ( 'this probably \not what we want' , 
                             ^^
```

That sequence `\n` is going to interpreted as a newline character, not as the character `n`. So, backslash characters are also going to need to be escaped.

et al.

Comment: Yes, i know about that, but codeigniter give me backup without quote at all, here's an example. If the data less than 100, i can fix that, but it's 12000 rows of data, so i cant edit it one by one. https://imgur.com/a/6SbyU

Comment: So, if you know about that... your question isn't really about how to get a restore to run  Your question is really about how to get CodeIgniter to properly escape values and enclose them in single quotes when it writes a "backup".  My question...  is there some reason we aren't using the `mysqldump` utility to produce a backup?

Comment: Yeah, i know, i hope i knew it faster, the auto backup already running for 1 months and i need to restore because of human error, now i'm changing to mysqldump-php library. Sorry i can't accept your answer since it's not really solving my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem should be solved by the following commit:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/a9194650e6ae387be29aacfdf4b1b27a5c60ca34

See this issue for reference:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5276